# link_to with dynamic :class style in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How would one structure a link_to in rails based enabling and disabling it with a class, so for example a disable link would look like this;

```
<%= link_to 'something', :somewhere, :class => 'btn btn-primary disabled' %>
```

but enabled would look like this

```
<%= link_to 'something', :somewhere, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

Now rather then doing this;

```
<% if current_user.is_admin? %>
   <%= link_to 'something', :somewhere, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% else %>
   <%= link_to 'something', :somewhere, :class => 'btn btn-primary disabled' %>
<% end %>
```

is there a cleaner and simple way of doing it ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can do this in two ways:

**string interpolation**

```
<%= link_to 'something', :somewhere, :class => "btn btn-primary #{current_user.is_admin? ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}" %>
```

**link_to_if**

now this doesn't really deal with the class but it makes the link a simple text if the condition is not satisfied

```
<%= link_to_if current_user.is_admin?, 'something', :somewhere, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```